# What is the purpose of enclosing @RenderSection with @section in a layout?

Tags: asp.net-core

Normally the top level layout view contains `RenderSection` as follows.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    Other omitted contents go here.
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I understand that any view using this layout can specify its own contribution to the optional section via `@section Scripts{...}` as follows.

```
@{
    Layout="_Layout";
}


other omitted contents go here.

@section Scripts
{
  this content will be rendered by RenderSection specified in _Layout
}
```

## Question

Now I compare with another layout view as follows

```
@{
    Layout = "/Areas/Identity/Pages/_Layout.cshtml";
}



@section Scripts {
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
}
```

I don't understand what  the purpose of sandwiching `RenderSection` in `@section  Scripts`.

In my thought experiment, sandwiching `RenderSection` in `@section` should cause infinitely self-referencing and end with stackoverflow error. But it does not happen. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Razor sections exist per-layout.

This means that your main layout `_Layout` has a section `Scripts` but that does not necessarily mean that other layouts also have such a section. Only the `existence` of a `RenderSection` call makes a layout have such a section.

Now, if you extend layouts by having a layout that itself has a layout, then you can fill the section of the outer layout within the inner layout. But views inside cannot access the sections of the outer layout directly. So instead, you will have to “forward” the sections you want to make available to the Razor view.

Note that the way you have written it will *always* make the outer layout have a filled `Scripts` section, even if the inner `Scripts` section does not have content. You can avoid doing so by checking in the inner layout whether the section is filled:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("Scripts"))
{
    @section Scripts
    {
        @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts")
    }
}
```

This will effectively forwards the section to the outer layout **iff** the view has a scripts section defined.

Comment: Out of topic: Do you know the reason why the main layout `_Layout`  uses `@RenderSection` instead of `@await RenderSectionAsync`? In my  understanding, using `async` is better because it can make the application scalable.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Apparently, [that was just an oversight](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13091) and this will probably change at some point for the 5.0 release.

Comment: Thank you very much poke! Asp.net Core 5.0 will be released in the incoming September, right?

Comment: ASP.NET Core 5, along with .NET 5, will be released somewhen in 2020. We will have 3.0 very soonish, and then 3.1 (the LTS release) towards the end of this year.