# Layout Scripts not running on ajax loaded partial view

Tags: c#, layout, asp.net-core-mvc, partial-views

I have the scripts needed for my theme in my layout page and all the views load perfectly with the scripts, but when i try to load a partial view with ajax, the html of the partial view loads perfectly except that my script do not run anymore. If i try to add the scripts in my partial view, it creates and error saying  *"ex: $ jquery is missing"*  when in fact it was loaded from the layout page and then the partial page which then they cancel each other. I will list my views and partial views below, any help will be really appreciated.

Layout Page::

```
<head>
    <title>UNSLegalFinanceSolutions</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <partial name="_Scripts" /> <!--Here the scripts mentioned above-->
</head>

<body  class="header-tablet-and-mobile-fixed aside-enabled">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-root">
        <div class="page d-flex flex-row flex-column-fluid">
            <partial name="_Sidebar" />
            <div class="wrapper d-flex flex-column flex-row-fluid" id="kt_wrapper">
                <div id="kt_header" style="" class="header align-items-stretch">
                    <partial name="_Topbar" />
                    <partial name="_Toolbar" />
                </div>
                <div class="content d-flex flex-column flex-column-fluid" id="kt_content">
                    <div class="post d-flex flex-column-fluid" id="kt_post">
                        <div id="kt_content_container" class="container-xxl">
                            <alerts></alerts>
                            <div class="p-lg-17">
                                @RenderBody()
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

Index View where the partial view needs to load::

```
<a class="btn btn-sm btn-light btn-active-primary me-4 mf-4 pt-4 h-40px w-100" id="Submit">@Resource.Search</a>
 <script>
        $("#Submit").click(function(){
            var company = $("#CompanyId").val();
            var caseNumber = $("#CaseNumber").val();
                        $.ajax({
                    url: "/Case/CasesList",
                    data: {companyId :company,caseNumber:caseNumber},
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $('#search').html(response);
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
<div class="card">
    <div id="search"></div>
</div>
```

Partial View::

```
@model List<CasesViewModel>

<div class="card-body py-3">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-row-dashed table-row-gray-300 align-middle gs-0 gy-4">
            <thead>
                <tr class="fw-bolder text-muted fs-6 text-gray-800 border-bottom-2 border-gray-200">
                    <th>@Resource.CaseNumber</th>
                    <th style="width:2%">@Resource.Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr id="row_@item.CaseId">
                        <td>@item.CaseNumber</td>
                       
                        <td>
                               <a class="menu-link px-5 justify-content-between"  asp-action="Edit" asp-route-caseId="@item.CaseId"><span>Edit</span> <i class="fas fa-pen texprimary"></i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Does this answer useful to you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57475263/what-is-the-purpose-of-enclosing-rendersection-with-section-in-a-layout)

Comment: No! I have already tried this and didn't work.

Comment: `but when i try to load a partial view with ajax, the html of the partial view loads perfectly except that my script do not run anymore. ` are you sure the partial rendered successfully by ajax call? If you want to use jquery in Index main page, you must put the js code in `@section Scripts{}` . For partial view, you can just use  js by `<script>` in partial view.